# How do I inject variables into my code that have been brought in via XMLHttpRequest(AJAX)?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my problem:
I am creating a quiz system on my website, and I am working on sending the question info over to the page using AJAX. This is my procedure:

1. Page Loads
2. XMLHTTP Request sent to request.php to request question info
3. request.php pulls info out from MySQL database
4. request.php sends 4 script tags, each with a variable (title, question, questiondata, type of question)

This is when my problem occurs. When I get these 4 variables, the page has already loaded. Because the variables have been echoed in after the page has loaded, the variables can't be accessed because they have not initialized. I have also tried to send a function with the variables in it, but the function is not initialized. How can I access these variables?

What can I add, either to the injected code or the code in the question page,

OR

What is a different approach?

Thank you so much!

(Please try to not use JQuery)

Comment: Had you try echo json_encode() the result from server and catch the response with JSON?

Comment: @ahmed No, how would I do that?

Comment: Can you show us your code? What have you attempted already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:
On server:

```
echo json_encode(Array('result' => 1));
```

On client side you catch the response using JSON library:

```
$.ajax({
...,
success: function(response){
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    //By this you can get response as an object
}
});
```

Include JSON library from here  :     `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20150503/json2.js`

Comment: Does this use jquery?

Comment: My answer does. the $.ajax() is a jquery function. do you use jquery?

Comment: Kind of (I am not very good at it). Does the .ajax function request the info, and if so, how do I specify the url that it does it at?

Comment: Here is an example (look at the end of the article): http://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/

Comment: I have one last question (Sorry, I am really bad at jquery): This is my response: `Object {topic: "Randomness", question: "Dis question much new", questioncode: "&#60;div class="snippet-container"&#62;&#60;div cl…name="pizza" value="cats"&#62;Cats &#60;/div&#62;", type: "c"}` How  do I convert the object into the 4 javascript variables that I can use?

Comment: If you could please help me with this final part, that would be great. Thank you so much for all of your previous help!!!

Comment: The response is ready to use. Just call it by var topic = response.topic and you get: 'Randomness'

Comment: Thank you so much ahmed! You have been an amazing help!